# what is correct way of reference to value in object/map type value in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

**Objective**: To assign particular key value while creating resource

**Variable.tf:**

```
variable "vnet_address_space" {
    type = map(list(string))
    default = {
        "Dev"  = ["xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/20"]
        "Stage" = ["xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/20"]
        "Prod" = ["xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/20"]
    }
}
```

Now I use below code to create VNET with address space based on environment i.e Dev,Stage,Prod etc

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.hub_vnet_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  for_each = {for k,v in var.vnet_address_space: k=>v if k == "Dev"}
  address_space       =  var.vnet_address_space.Dev
  dns_servers         = var.dns_servers
  tags     = {
    environment = "${var.env}"
    costcentre = "14500"
  }
  dynamic "ddos_protection_plan" {
    for_each = local.if_ddos_enabled

    content {
      id     = azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan.ddos[0].id
      enable = false
    }
  }
}
```

**Error**:

```
Error: Invalid value for input variable
│ 
│   on /home/circleci/workingfiles/*********output.tfvars.json line 15:
│   15:   "vnet_address_space": [
│   16:     "xx.xx.0.0/24",
│   17:     "xx.xx.0.0/20",
│   18:     "xx.xx.0.0/24",
│   19:     "xx.xx.0.0/20"
│   20:   ],
│ 
│ The given value is not suitable for var.vnet_address_space declared at variables.tf:25,1-30: map of list of string required.
╵
```

How Should I tell Terraform, take Dev Address space in variable and create vnet ?

Please help

Comment: Well, it simply cannot work with a list, because it's a single string value. Is there any network in particular from e.g., `Dev` that you would like to use? Also, the value assigned to variable is a wrong type. It should be something like `vnet_address_space  = {Dev = [...], Stage=[...], Prod=[...]}` based on the variable definition.

Comment: @MarkoE so do you mean variable definition type is wrong ? basically my idea is when I am creating vnet for Dev / use stage address space when I create for Stage and so on, it should use corresponding default value from variable definition. can you please tell me correct way of defining that variable  ? which type it should be ?

Comment: Marcin's answer is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that your `output.tfvars.json` is incorrect. It has nothing to do with your `azurerm_virtual_network`. In your `output.tfvars.json` you should have:

```
vnet_address_space = {
        "Dev"  = ["xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/20"]
        "Stage" = ["xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/20"]
        "Prod" = ["xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/20"]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin now it works as expected  so basically its not taking default value but my tfvars is overriding and it has wrong definition there as list hence I need to give dictionary way  of  values as per your suggestion..