# Issue while creating multiple subnets using for_each in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

**Context:** This is continuation of what I was doing at below post.

[what is correct way of reference to value in object/map type value in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73349363/what-is-correct-way-of-reference-to-value-in-object-map-type-value-in-terraform?noredirect=1#comment129534953_73349363)

**Objective**: Trying to create subnets in loop using `for_each` in terraform

**My terraform.tfvars.json**: (only I have mentioned variable realated to my problem I am facing)

```
 "subnets" : {
        "Dev" :
        [  
        {"gw_snet":{
          "name"                 : "GatewaySubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.1.0/24"]
        },
        "dns-snet" : {
          "name"                 : "InboundDNSSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.2.0/24"]
        },
        "common_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "Common",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.3.0/24"]
        },
        "clientdata_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "ClientDataSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.4.0/20"]
        }}
        ],
        "Stage" :
        [  
        {"gw_snet":{
          "name"                 : "GatewaySubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.1.0/24"]
        },
        "dns-snet" : {
          "name"                 : "InboundDNSSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.2.0/24"]
        },
        "common_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "Common",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.3.0/24"]
        },
        "clientdata_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "ClientDataSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.4.0/20"]
        }}
        ],
        "Prod" :
        [  
        {"gw_snet":{
          "name"                 : "GatewaySubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.1.0/24"]
        },
        "dns-snet" : {
          "name"                 : "InboundDNSSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.2.0/24"]
        },
        "common_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "Common",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.3.0/24"]
        },
        "clientdata_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "ClientDataSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.4.0/20"]
        }}
        ]
      }
```

**My vnet creation code:**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.hub_vnet_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  for_each = {for k,v in var.vnet_address_space: k=>v if k == "Dev"}
  address_space       =  each.value
  dns_servers         = var.dns_servers
  tags     = {
    environment = "${var.env}"
    costcentre = "14500"
  }
  dynamic "ddos_protection_plan" {
    for_each = local.if_ddos_enabled

    content {
      id     = azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan.ddos[0].id
      enable = false
    }
  }
}
```

**I am trying to create subnets with for_each like below**

```
  resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  for_each = {for k,v in var.subnets: k=>v if k == "Dev"}
  name                 = each.value.name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.address_prefixes]
  virtual_network_name = var.hub_vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
}
```

Error I get:

No errors in my terraform plan, its not creating vnet also as my plan is not validated.

Is my subnets variable definition ok ?

I guess the below is not working at all.. correct way of accessing this nested value ?

```
  name                 = each.value.name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.address_prefixes]
```

Please help me to identify issue

Comment: So you only want Dev subnets to be created?

Comment: Yes, in dev environment, 4 subnets, if I give as stage, then it has to create these 4 subnets in stage environment. It depends on which environment I pass it has to create there. In above example, since I gave Dev as environment, it has to pickup corresponding address_prefix and create those 4 subnets

Comment: Ok, so you know this `for_each = {for k,v in var.subnets: k=>v if k == "Dev"}` means it will create subnets for **Dev** only?

Comment: Yes since I gave Dev, create for dev only

Comment: You are also aware that if you change the value at a later stage to something else than Dev it will destroy previously created subnets?

Comment: It wont, actually we are deploying this into different subscription all together, so I run this whole flow via devops pipeline, I pass environment code as substitution variable which is mapped to particular subscription. I.e  `for_each = {for k,v in var.subnets: k=>v if k == "${var.env}"}` this var.env represent environment tagged to a subscription. My whole idea is to have single terraform config to create resource in respective environment(subscription) without hardcoding values for environment specific

Comment: Ah, well, that's an important information.

Comment: I am sure I missing crucial thing in   `resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" ` in above code ..  my wild guess is I am not able to access nested variable properly or I am not using proper syntax.. not able to reproduce it, as I am not seeing any errors in plan

Comment: Not really sure if the one with providing variable value will work with `for_each` as it can only work with values that are known, but I think I might have an answer for you.

Comment: `for_each` can for with computed values, but not in the key.

Comment: Both answers are correct and solved by issue. I wanted to make both as correct. sadly stack overflow wont allow it.. Thanks for your valuable time and help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is seeming much more complex than it really is. What you seek, I believe, is the [lookup](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/lookup) function. Just lookup your `var.env` in the map. Your current data structure doesn't make much sense. I show it here as locals with just few enough to show the structure.

```
locals {
  subnets = {
    "Dev" = [
      {
        "some_name_a" = {
          name             = "SomeOtherNameA",
          address_prefixes = ["10.1.1.0/24"]
        },
        "some_name_b" = {
          name             = "SomeOtherNameB",
          address_prefixes = ["10.1.2.0/24"]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Stage" = [
      {
        "some_name_a" = {
          name             = "SomeOtherNameA",
          address_prefixes = ["10.1.1.0/24"]
        },
        "some_name_b" = {
          name             = "SomeOtherNameB",
          address_prefixes = ["10.1.2.0/24"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So each environment section is a list of length one of an object with a key per some network name you don't need housing an object that actually defines your configuration. What you need is much more simple.

```
locals {
  subnets = {
    "Dev" = [
      {
        name             = "SomeOtherNameA",
        address_prefixes = ["10.1.1.0/24"]
      },
      {
        name             = "SomeOtherNameB",
        address_prefixes = ["10.1.2.0/24"]
      }
    ],
    "Stage" = [
      {
        name             = "SomeOtherNameA",
        address_prefixes = ["10.1.1.0/24"]
      },
      {
        name             = "SomeOtherNameB",
        address_prefixes = ["10.1.2.0/24"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In this case you can use:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  for_each = { for v in lookup(var.subnets, var.env, []) : v.name => v.address_prefixes }

  name                 = each.key
  address_prefixes     = each.value
  virtual_network_name = var.hub_vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
}
```

Or even more simple, given your data:

```
locals {
  subnets_simple = {
    "Dev" = {
      "SomeOtherNameA" = ["10.1.1.0/24"]
      "SomeOtherNameB" = ["10.1.2.0/24"]
    },
    "Stage" = {
      "SomeOtherNameA" = ["10.1.1.0/24"]
      "SomeOtherNameB" = ["10.1.2.0/24"]
    },
  }
}
```

In this case, you should be able to simply use:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  for_each = lookup(var.subnets, var.env, {})

  name                 = each.key
  address_prefixes     = each.value
  virtual_network_name = var.hub_vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
}
```

Comment: I tried last solution, got this  ` for_each = lookup(var.subnets, env, {})
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.` any how thanks for guidance
╵

Comment: I'm guessing it should probably be `for_each = lookup(var.subnets, var.env, {})`.

Comment: @MarkoE Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: No worries, otherwise it's a great answer, much simpler than mine. :)

Comment: Both answers work , I should have option to make both answers correct. Sad that I dont have option

Comment: Most of us really just want to make the community better. I can only speak for me, but I really don't mind either way, but I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Thanks for all wonderful people who help others to learn better and grow better...

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution to which I got (based on your input) is this:

```
locals {
   net_subnets = merge([
    for env, network in var.subnets : {
      for k, v in network[0] :
      "${k}-${v.name}" => {
        subnet_name      = v.name
        address_prefixes = v.address_prefixes
      } if env == "Dev"
  }]...)
}
```

Here `merge` built-in function [1] and expanding function argument [2] are used. This will result in the output:

```
> local.net_subnets
{
  "clientdata_snet-ClientDataSubnet" = {
    "address_prefixes" = [
      "10.1.4.0/20",
    ]
    "subnet_name" = "ClientDataSubnet"
  }
  "common_snet-Common" = {
    "address_prefixes" = [
      "10.1.3.0/24",
    ]
    "subnet_name" = "Common"
  }
  "dns-snet-InboundDNSSubnet" = {
    "address_prefixes" = [
      "10.1.2.0/24",
    ]
    "subnet_name" = "InboundDNSSubnet"
  }
  "gw_snet-GatewaySubnet" = {
    "address_prefixes" = [
      "10.1.1.0/24",
    ]
    "subnet_name" = "GatewaySubnet"
  }
}
```

That means you can do `for_each` on that variable value, where the keys will be a combination of the `*-snet` key and `name` from the `var.subnets` variable. Then, the resource code block should look like:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  for_each             = local.net_subnets
  name                 = each.value.subnet_name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
  virtual_network_name = var.hub_vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
}
```

In order to avoid the issue with pre-computed values required for `for_each`, it might be the best to use the `locals` block and just use the same logic for the pipeline, i.e., instead of using `if env == "Dev"`, just use `if env == var.env`. Or alternatively define three local variables for each of the environments.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/merge

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments

Comment: your logic of locals working, but now I am getting issue at below  `virtual_network_name = var.hub_vnet_name ` it said vnet not found then I tried with `  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name`  then `got │ Because azurerm_virtual_network.vnet has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.` .

Comment: That is a topic for another question.

Comment: No Problem will draft one hmm

Comment: I have created another post as you suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73360687/how-to-use-output-value-in-same-root-module-for-creating-another-resource