# How to use output value in same root module for creating another resource

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, azure-rm

**Context:** This is continuation of below post which I raised
[Issue while creating multiple subnets using for_each in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73351761/issue-while-creating-multiple-subnets-using-for-each-in-terraform)

**Objective**: How to use output value of one resource created and use that for creating another resource in same root module

**What I tried:**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.hub_vnet_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  for_each = {for k,v in var.vnet_address_space: k=>v if k == "${var.env}"}
  address_space       =  each.value
  dns_servers         = var.dns_servers
  tags     = {
    environment = "${var.env}"
    costcentre = "14500"
  }
  dynamic "ddos_protection_plan" {
    for_each = local.if_ddos_enabled

    content {
      id     = azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan.ddos[0].id
      enable = false
    }
  }
}

output "azurerm_vnets_names" {
    value = values(azurerm_virtual_network.vnet)[*].name
             
}
```

Till above point its working and I see output of as

```
Outputs:

azurerm_vnets_names = [
  "vnet-hub",
]
```

Now as next step I am trying to create Subnets in loop as below

**tfvars.json:**

```
"subnets" : {
        "Dev" :
        [  
        {"gw_snet":{
          "name"                 : "GatewaySubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.1.0/24"]
        },
        "dns-snet" : {
          "name"                 : "InboundDNSSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.2.0/24"]
        },
        "common_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "Common",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.3.0/24"]
        },
        "clientdata_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "ClientDataSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.4.0/20"]
        }}
        ],
        "Stage" :
        [  
        {"gw_snet":{
          "name"                 : "GatewaySubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.1.0/24"]
        },
        "dns-snet" : {
          "name"                 : "InboundDNSSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.2.0/24"]
        },
        "common_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "Common",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.3.0/24"]
        },
        "clientdata_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "ClientDataSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.4.0/20"]
        }}
        ],
        "Prod" :
        [  
        {"gw_snet":{
          "name"                 : "GatewaySubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.1.0/24"]
        },
        "dns-snet" : {
          "name"                 : "InboundDNSSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.2.0/24"]
        },
        "common_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "Common",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.3.0/24"]
        },
        "clientdata_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "ClientDataSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.4.0/20"]
        }}
        ]
      }
```

**In my main.tf:**

```
locals {
   net_subnets = merge([
    for env, network in var.subnets : {
      for k, v in network[0] :
      "${k}-${v.name}" => {
        subnet_name      = v.name
        address_prefixes = v.address_prefixes
      } if env == "Dev"
  }]...)
}


#Creating subnets

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  for_each             = local.net_subnets
  name                 = each.value.subnet_name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
}
```

Now below line is erroring out

```
virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet.name
```

saying " since I used `for_each` in creating vnet I cannot use that above way

Now since I see output variable which I defined above which is `azurerm_vnets_names` , I tried to refer that as below

```
virtual_network_name = azurerm_vnets_names
```

it didnt work

Then

I tried to add datasource

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "vnet-hub"
  resource_group_name = "hub"
}
```

then tried below:

```
virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet.name
```

Again error says that.. Its not declared.

I tried below one also, didnt work

```
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[*].name
```

Please help me with identifying issue.

Comment: Wait, this is all in the same tf file? The outputs and the rest? If so, you don't need outputs.

Comment: Yes same tf file, i am not able to get vnet name to use it in  `  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet.name ` I tried output to get value for vnet from vnet resource block, like i explained in above post, i tried various methods but i am not able to get value for vnet.name properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is erroring out because `azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet` is a set, not a single value. You created `azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet` with a `for_each`, so Terraform thinks there can be more than one `azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet` resource, and you aren't telling it which one to use. This should be clear if you look at the error message Terraform is giving you.

```
virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet.name
```

---

This is invalid Terraform syntax:

```
virtual_network_name = azurerm_vnets_names
```

Outputs are only to be referenced by parent modules. In the root module outputs are only used for outputting things to the output log of your `terraform apply` run. You don't declare outputs to use in the same module that you declare them in.

---

The fix is to actually pull out the value you need from the `azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet` set:

```
virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet[var.env].name
```

Although, I think you could clean up the code even more by not using a `for_each` at all in your `azurerm_virtual_nework.vnet` resource, and just lookup the value from your map instead of greatly overcomplicating everything by trying to loop over it your map with an if statement: `var.vnet_address_space[var.env]`.

Comment: Hi @mark-b I get now this one after changing above incode...  `│ A managed resource "azurerm_virtual_nework" "vnet" has not been declared in the root module.`

Comment: Oh my goodness, thanks @Mark-B its working now. very silly mistake, I had a typo "it was nework instead network" It now working as intended

Comment: just would like know, how to put that entire vnet set to how it is structured ? because as next phase of code, I need to refer to subnet information ... is that output command make sense or different way to know exactly that vnet and subnet structure look like from referencing perspective with in terraform code. for example before I use this for_each and creating subets without loop like `subnet_id  = azurerm_subnet.clientdata_snet[0].id`  what is correctway to refer this when I use `for_each` like this   `subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.clientdata_snet[var.env][0].id` ?